# jQuery function not called in jsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

Here is my code in jsFiddle:

### http://jsfiddle.net/AXXGZ/4/

> #### html
>
> ```html
> <html>
>     <body>
>         <a href="abc.com", id="a">aa</a>
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> #### javascript
>
> ```js
> $('#a').click(function(){
>     alert ('aa');
>
> })
> ```
>
> #### run
>
> `onLoad` with MooTools 1.3.2

Why is my `click` callback function not called?

Comment: Too difficult to post your code here?

Comment: @Oded wouldn't have helped any, the issue was in the fiddle

Comment: @mazlix - fair enough, in this case.

Comment: @hristo you gave the solution first could u post it as an answer so i can mark it

Answer (score 6):

Because, you're using mootools on the fiddle... always happens to me too :p

http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/AXXGZ/6/

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using jQuery. Select it from the drop-down at the left and your code works.

However your HTML also has a syntax error; you should remove the comma from this tag:

```
<a href="abc.com", id="a">aa</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using jQuery in your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/AXXGZ/14/

Answer (score 1):

You're using mootools, look
http://jsfiddle.net/AKbnp/4/

Edit: Damn...Almost 3 answers before mine...

Answer (score 1):

When jsfiddle loads, it sets Mootools as the default JavaScript Framework. Your syntax looks like jQuery... so you should select it.

[image: jsfiddle jQuery]

I hope this helps.
Hristo